# how to use jpanel with paint (or repaint)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, repaint

I'm a newbie to the paint/graphics and wonder how to add a JPanel to my code in such way that the entire graphics will be on a JPanel and not on the JFrame.

In other words, I'm trying to create a GUI that will allow me to do this:
on the RIGHT side show the nice movement of the lines **on a JPanel**
on the LEFT side, add a JTextArea (on a JPanel) that will show the coordination of the graphics.

- This is a simplification of a bigger problem but I guess the code here is easier to understand.

Thank you!!!

(picture below, moving lines or simply run the code)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test extends JFrame implements Runnable  
{
    private Line2D line;

public Test()
{
    super("testing");
    this.setBounds( 500, 500, 500, 500 );
    this.setVisible( true );
}

public void paint( Graphics g ) 
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.draw(line); 
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    int x=50;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep( 50 );

            line = new Line2D.Float(100+x, 100+x, 250-x, 260+x%2);
            x++;
            repaint();
            if (x==5000)
                break;

        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String args[])
{
    Thread thread = new Thread (new Test());
    thread.start();
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Instead of implementing `Runnable`, establish an `ActionListener` that calls `repaint()`.  Call it from a Swing `Timer`.
2. There are 2 ways to do this.

   - Extend a `JComponent` or `JPanel`
   - Draw in a `BufferedImage` and add that to an `ImageIcon` in a `JLabel`.
3. If extending a component, use `JComponent` if you do not need to add further children, or `JPanel` if you do.  For either, *override `paintComponent(Graphics)` instead of `paint(Graphics)`.*
4. The `BufferedImage` might be a better choice for this use-case, since it seems to be animating a (supposedly intentionally persistant) series of lines.
5. Swing GUIs should be started on the EDT.
6. Don't call `setBounds`!  Instead, set a preferred size to the custom component, use sensible values for the constructor of the text area, and combine them with layouts (and appropriate padding and borders), then call `pack()` on the frame after all components are added.
7. There is an NPE if the JRE calls `repaint()` prior to the `Thread` starting.

---

..What was the question?  Oh right, if it can be inferred that the question is "How to combine other components with a custom painted component?" - use a nested layout.  see the [Nested Layout example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556).

[image]

If using a `BufferedImage` as backing store, you might place it like the image in that example, except that you would leave out the `JTable` above that, as well as the `JSplitPane`.

Comment: Thank you! I extended the JPanel and used the paintComponent, that did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the proper way to do this.